# If A is semisimple algebra then every A-module is completely reducible

Tags: ring-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras, semi-simple-rings

A semisimple Algebra means the regular module is completely reducible. Let $A= \sum_{i}A_{i}$ where $A_{i}$ is irreducible sub modules of A. Suppose *V* is A-module. I tried to define a map between the $A_{i}$ and *V*.
$$\theta_{i}: A_{i} \longrightarrow V$$
$$ x_{i}\mapsto vx_{i} $$
the map is homomorphism so
$A_{i}\setminus ker(\theta_{i})$  is isomorphic to $\theta (A_{i}) \subseteq V$
the kernel is $\{0\}$ since $A_{i}$ is irreducible, so $A_{i}$  is isomorphic to $\theta_{i} (A_{i}) \subseteq V$.

- $\theta_{i} (A_{i})$ is irreducible because of the isomorphic. Now, $\oplus \sum_{i} \theta_{i} (A_{i})$ is the direct sum of irreducible V submodules.

$\oplus \sum_{i}A_{i}$  is isomorphic to $\oplus \sum_{i} \theta_{i} (A_{i})$, i.e  $A$ is isomorphic to $\oplus \sum_{i} \theta_{i} (A_{i})$

If the steps are right, how can I show that $\oplus \sum_{i} \theta_{i} (A_{i})=  V$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is semisimple as (right) $A$-module, $V$ is a (right) $A$-module and $v\in V$.

$\ker(A\to vA)$ is a submodule of $A$ thus it has a complementary module $A =\ker(A\to vA)\oplus B$ $$B\cong \ker(A\to vA)\backslash A\cong vA$$ so that $vA\cong B$ is a submodule of $A$, it is semisimple.

For another cyclic submodule $wA\subset V$ and $U\subset V$ semisimple we have that $$U= (wA\cap U)\oplus S \qquad \implies wA+U = wA\oplus S$$ is semisimple.

Thus every (finitely generated) $A$-module is semisimple.

Comment: Why *U* is semisimple? Did you claim that every module has a semisimple submodule?

Comment: We want to show that $U$ semisimple implies $U+wA$ semisimple to get that $V=\sum_{j=1}^J w_jA$ is semisimple (note that I assumed $V$ finitely generated)

Comment: but how would you say that *U* is semisimple? *U* is arbitrary submodule? is there a theory that says for finite *A*-module there exist semisimple submodule?

Comment: No... $V=\sum_{j=1}^J w_j A$. At first $U=0$ then $U+w_1A$ is semisimple, then $U=w_1A$ and  $U+w_2A$ is semisimple, then $U=w_1A+w_2A$ and $U+w_3A$ is semisimple, and so on until we proved that $V$ is semisimple.

Comment: What is $S$? ---

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $U$ is semisimple the intersection $wA\cap U$ has a complementary module

Answer (score 1):

I tried to define a map between the $A$ and *V*.

For some *v $\in$ V* define the following map:

$$\theta: A \longrightarrow V$$
$$ x\mapsto vx $$
the map is homomorphism so
$A\setminus ker(\theta)$  is isomorphic to $\theta (A) \subseteq V$

$\theta (A) = vA$ $\subset V$

Then I proved that $A\setminus ker(\theta)$  is completely reducible so is $vA$

So $vA$ can be written as sum of irreducible submodules $V_{\alpha}$

$V= \sum_{v \in\ V\setminus {0}} vA = \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} \sum V_{\alpha}$

So $V$ is written as sum of irreducible submodules so $V$ is completely reducible